# How to enable Work Orders using Metadata API

Tags: metadata-api, fieldservice, work-order

I was hoping to deploy a package to my production org, but it seems that I must check off "Enable Work Orders" in Field Service Settings on my own.  Is that the case?

I was hoping that there'd be a `FieldService.settings` or something in `OrgPreference.settings`, which seems like the places Salesforce would put that checkbox.

Is there a way to enable Work Orders using the Metadata API (or even the Tooling API), or must I do it using the UI?